# html body gwt click event

Tags: html, events, gwt, click

html file has two textbox and one button.
but i need to generate click event when i only click outside of the two textboxes and button 
element.how can i do that.

RootPanel.get().addEventListener or something like that?? help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typing anywhere in the browser window will trigger alert pop-up:

```
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new Event.NativePreviewHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
    NativeEvent ne = event.getNativeEvent();
    if (KeyDownEvent.getType().getName().equals(ne.getType())) {
      Window.alert("who fired me last?"
          + event.getNativeEvent().getCurrentEventTarget()
          + "\nevent target:" + event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is the best possible approach to intercept all event.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, if `RootPanel.get().addEventListener` works, but you can add another panel, which contains the three elements. To the new panel you can add an listener.